# Can I limit the display of a resultset within PHP based on ID?

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

Assume I have the following result set from a mysql DB call (basic example, main will have much more data):

```
customerID   |   name     |     item     |     price
====================================================
11111        |   John     |    pizza     |   10.00
11111        |   John     |    burger    |   5.00
11111        |   John     |    drink     |   2.00
22222        |   Mike     |    lasagna   |   11.00
22222        |   Mike     |    drink     |   2.00
33333        |   Sam      |    burger    |   5.00
33333        |   Sam      |    fries     |   3.00
33333        |   Sam      |    shake     |   5.00
33333        |   Sam      |    drink     |   2.00
```

I want to display the results in a tabular form but limit the times customerID and name appear, as well as show a subtotal by each customer:

```
customerID   |    name    |   item    |    price
===================================================
11111        |    John    |  pizza    |   10.00
             |            |  burger   |   5.00
             |            |  drink    |   2.00
             |            |           |   **17.00**
             |            |           |
22222        |    Mike    |  lasagna  |   11.00
             |            |  drink    |   2.00
             |            |           |   **13.00**
             |            |           |
33333        |    Sam     |  burger   |   5.00
             |            |  fries    |   3.00
             |            |  shake    |   5.00
             |            |  drink    |   2.00
             |            |           |   **15.00**
```

I know I **could** make multiple DB calls but this is wasteful when it can be done in one. I am having problems cycling through my result set in table 1 and properly formatting with PHP using as shown in table 2. Is it possible the way I have it shown or do I **have** to make multiple DB calls to do so?

Comment: You can return the group totals alongside the ordinary rows with `GROUP BY customerID, name WITH ROLLUP` syntax ([more about it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)), so no multiple queries would be required. I would have done all the other work in the client code, as it's essentially a representation issue.

Comment: Don't do it database side, this is basic application logic. Just loop through the results and create a new array with your desired structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better solved directly in PHP, because you will be free to modify the output as you wish.

So basically you will do something like (untested):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT costumerID, name, item, price
                    FROM orders 
                    ORDER BY customerID, item");

echo "<table id='orders'>".
      "<tr><th>Name</th>".
      "<th>Item</th>".
      "<th>Price</th></tr>";

$lastCostumer = -1;
$subTotal = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
     {
     // New costumer
     if ($lastCostumer != $row['costumerID'])
           {
           // Write the subtotal of previous costumer, unless this is the 1st one
           if ($lastCostumer != -1)
              echo "<tr><td></td>".
                   "<td></td>".
                   "<td><b>**".$subTotal."**</b></td></tr>";

           $subTotal = 0; 
           echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['item']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['price']."</td></tr>";

           $subTotal = $subTotal + $row['price'];
           $lastCostumer = $row['costumerID'];
           }
     else // Same costumer
           {
           echo "<tr><td></td>".  // Don't write the name
                "<td>".$row['item']."</td>".
                "<td>".$row['price']."</td></tr>";

           $subTotal = $subTotal + $row['price'];
           }
     }

// Write the subtotal of last costumer
echo "<tr><td></td>".
     "<td></td>".
     "<td><b>**".$subTotal."**</b></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - Your answer does not print the customerID as needed but I get the idea. It seems your subtotal would continue to grow with each new customer in the example, ultimately, it would have to be within the while results exists loop and nulled at the start of every customer.

Comment: @JM4: no, there is a `$subTotal = 0;` line in the "new costumer" block, which resets the counter.

Comment: got it - exactly what I was looking for - the $lastCustomer = -1 was my missing piece. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use group_concat() to achieve this.

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS items, GROUP_CONCAT(price) AS prices, SUM(price) AS total FROM ... GROUP BY id
```

Here you get items and price as comma separated strings and also get total in another column.

group_concat can have it's own order, for more info look at this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: You **can** use `GROUP_CONCAT`, it is not a must, this is better solved in PHP.

Comment: @ali - thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to test it out but then I would essentially need to use an explode function to separate the items and build an array. In the end, it seems like that is just doing the work the DB already did but I will play with it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single DB call.  Just loop through the results in PHP and output the table accordingly.  In other words, I don't thing this is a database issues so much as it is an issue in determining how you want to loop through the dataset and render the HTML elements.

Comment: I didn't look at it as a DB issue. My question is directly asking how to achieve this using PHP. Using a while loop makes sense but sorting the resultset is the issue given the ID will be returned in each row (i.e. as long as ID is the same as row before, do X, otherwise do Y).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CONCAT_WS operator in your (sub)query. Use `'<br/>'` as the seaparator. Then GROUP BY customerId.
There is, however a limit of 1024 characters for the output of CONCAT_WS.

Comment: I am trying not to use subqueries and don't think they are necessary here.

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to have SQL directly output HTML as it is difficult to mantein

Comment: @JM4 you can do this without subqueries. I just added the (sub) because I can't tell from here what your db looks like...

Comment: @nico you can also use a comma as the separator and treat the result as an array. Loop this array with foreach(). That way you don't fetch data you don't need.

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly: that I like much better!